# Is there a way to return two fields from SQLAlchemy / FastAPI relationship?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, fastapi

structure

```
.
└── sql_app
    ├── __init__.py
    ├── crud.py
    ├── database.py
    ├── main.py
    ├── models.py
    └── schemas.py
```

main.py

```
from typing import List

from fastapi import Depends, FastAPI, HTTPException
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from . import crud, models, schemas
from .database import SessionLocal, engine

models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

app = FastAPI()


# Dependency
def get_db():
    db = SessionLocal()
    try:
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()


@app.post("/users/", response_model=schemas.User)
def create_user(user: schemas.UserCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_user = crud.get_user_by_name(db, name=user.name)
    if db_user:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=400, detail="Name already registered")
    return crud.create_user(db=db, user=user)


@app.get("/users/", response_model=List[schemas.User])
def read_users(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    users = crud.get_users(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return users


@app.get("/users/{user_id}", response_model=schemas.User)
def read_user(user_id: int, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    db_user = crud.get_user(db, user_id=user_id)
    if db_user is None:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="User not found")
    return db_user


@app.post("/users/{user_id}/messages/", response_model=schemas.Message)
def create_message_for_user(
    user_id: int, message: schemas.MessageCreate, db: Session = Depends(get_db)
):
    return crud.create_user_message(db=db, message=message, user_id=user_id)


@app.get("/messages/", response_model=List[schemas.MessageWithUser])
def read_messages(skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100, db: Session = Depends(get_db)):
    messages = crud.get_messages(db, skip=skip, limit=limit)
    return messages
```

crud.py

```
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session

from . import models, schemas


def get_user(db: Session, user_id: int):
    return db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.id == user_id).first()


def get_user_by_name(db: Session, name: str):
    return db.query(models.User).filter(models.User.name == name).first()


def get_users(db: Session, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return db.query(models.User).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()


def create_user(db: Session, user: schemas.UserCreate):
    db_user = models.User(name=user.name)
    db.add(db_user)
    db.commit()
    db.refresh(db_user)
    return db_user


def get_messages(db: Session, skip: int = 0, limit: int = 100):
    return db.query(models.Message).offset(skip).limit(limit).all()


def create_user_message(db: Session, message: schemas.MessageCreate, user_id: int):
    db_item = models.Message(**message.dict(), user_id=user_id)
    db.add(db_item)
    db.commit()
db.refresh(db_item)
return db_item
```

database.py

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.declarative import declarative_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "sqlite:///./sql_app.db"
# SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = "postgresql://user:password@postgresserver/db"

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={"check_same_thread": False}
)
SessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base = declarative_base()
```

models.py

```
from sqlalchemy import Boolean, Column, ForeignKey, Integer, String
from sqlalchemy.orm import relationship

from .database import Base


class User(Base):
    __tablename__ = "users"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    name = Column(String, index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)

    messages = relationship("Message", back_populates="user")


class Message(Base):
    __tablename__ = "messages"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True, index=True)
    title = Column(String, index=True, unique=True, nullable=False)
    message = Column(String, index=False)
    user_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("users.id"))

    user = relationship("User", back_populates="messages")
```

schemas.py

```
from typing import List

from pydantic import BaseModel


class MessageBase(BaseModel):
    title: str
    message: str


class MessageCreate(MessageBase):
    pass


class Message(MessageBase):
    id: int
    user_id: int

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class UserBase(BaseModel):
    name: str


class UserCreate(UserBase):
    pass


class User(UserBase):
    id: int
    messages: List[Message] = []

    class Config:
        orm_mode = True


class UserIdentifier(UserBase):
    id: int
    name: str


class MessageWithUser(MessageBase):
    id: int
    title: str
    message: str
    user: UserIdentifier
```

Run cmd:

```
uvicorn sql_app.main:app --reload
```

Navigate to: 127.0.0.1:8000/docs

Add users and messages for users

Try to read messages

The example result is the correct format but it does not give a response just 500 error and the following

Error:

```
pydantic.error_wrappers.ValidationError: 4 validation errors for MessageWithUser
response -> 0
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
response -> 1
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
response -> 2
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
response -> 3
  value is not a valid dict (type=type_error.dict)
```

The expected output is what is shown in the example output of the docs page, with UserIdentifier being added to Message but not any other fields from User if there were any, in this case there is not

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that it is possible to cast a SqlAlchemy object with dependencies to a pydantic model out of the box.

@tiagolo (the creator of FastAPI) did this pydantic-sqlalchemy method that seems to do the trick of what you want:
https://github.com/tiangolo/pydantic-sqlalchemy

Otherwise, I think that you can create a list of `MessageWithUser` manually and return it.